# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_subdist' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, import, laravel-excel

I face problem and make me dizzy, what's wrong with this code and make my program in trouble

This is my error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_subdist' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `transaksi` (`id_subdist`, `id_toko`, `id_dso`, `id_rso`, `id_channel`, `id_outlet`, `id_produk`, `qty_pcs`, `harga`, `nama_promo`, `free_goods`, `total_qty_include_free_goods`, `disc_total`, `jumlah`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2021-09-22 07:32:43, 2021-09-22 07:32:43))

I check all code is no problem, I was doing create program upload excel to my program.
I'm using laravel 8.6 and I need column `id_subdist` not NULL.

there is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Transaksi;

use Session;

use App\Imports\TransaksiImport;
use App\Exports\TransaksiExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ImportTransaksi_Controller extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        $transaksi = Transaksi::all();
       
        return view('import.transaksi.index',['transaksi'=>$transaksi]);
    }   
    public function export_excel()
    {
        return Excel::download(new TransaksiExport, 'transaksi.xlsx');
    }
    public function import_excel(Request $request) 
    {
        // validasi
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
        ]);
 
        // menangkap file excel
        $file = $request->file('file');
 
        // membuat nama file unik
        $nama_file = rand().$file->getClientOriginalName();
 
        // upload ke folder file_transaksi di dalam folder public
        $file->move('file_transaksi',$nama_file);
 
        // import data
        Excel::import(new TransaksiImport, public_path('/file_transaksi/'.$nama_file));
 
        // notifikasi dengan session
        Session::flash('sukses','Data Transaksi Cuy Berhasil Diimport!');
 
        // alihkan halaman kembali
        return redirect('/transaksi');
    }

}
```

I'm check on my excel column `id_subdist` have value, but when run this program have error.

There is my web.php

```
`Route::get('/transaksi', 'ImportTransaksi_Controller@index');`
`Route::get('/transaksi/export_excel', 'ImportTransaksi_Controller@export_excel');`
`Route::post('/transaksi/import_excel', 'ImportTransaksi_Controller@import_excel')`
`Route::get('/import_transaksi', [ImportTransaksi_Controller::class, 'index'])->name('import_transaksi');`
```

Comment: possibly you forgot to make `id_subdist` auto-increment itself (besides being NON NULL)

Comment: `id_subdist` is not autoincrement is upload with excel

Comment: auto increment only for `id`

Comment: then put a value and not leave it empty

Comment: You try to insert null value to not null property column ...

Comment: there is value in excel column, and column can be fill with import excel

Comment: check your excel file and confirm that `id_subdist` column not null or empty

Comment: Hi @A.ANoman I was checked and is not null or empty. `id_subdist` on excel have value

Comment: Can you share TransaksiImport?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is my excel file, the solution is creating a new excel file and input new data, and the program can run.
Thank you, everyone.
I appreciate your help and answer.

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem, rather than creating new excel file add this code to your controller instead

```
 if (!isset($row['num'])) {
        return null;
    }
```

source: [Laravel excel don't detect my data in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345799/laravel-excel-dont-detect-my-data-in-file)